# How can I bind a control into a WPF listview column

Tags: wpf, listview, binding

I'm new to WPF so forgive me if I've missed something obvious

I have the following list view control (non relevent details removed for brevity)

```
<ListView>
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn Header="Type" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Type}"/>
      <GridViewColumn Header="Details" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Details}"/>
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

I add items to this list view in code behind

```
public void Add(LogEntry entry)
{
  ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
  item.Content = entry;
  listView.Items.Add(item);
}
```

where LogEntry has public string properties for "Type" and "Details"

So far, so good, all works lovely but..
I want my details property to be an element itself (TextBox or DockPanel containing various types of content)
How can I bind this Element to the list column?

Using the code above, Changing "Details" to an element I simply get the class name in the list box (e.g. System.Windows.Control.TextBox) as by default the cell displays the ToString() value of the property.
I have googled examples which use a DataTemplate but I can't find an example of binding an element to the content of a panel.
The control cannot be defined in xaml as its structure and contents are not known until runtime

The binding is one way (I only need to display the list, not update the underlying data structure)

To make my problem clearer, I want to bind the following list item

```
class LogEntry
{
  public string Type {get;}
  public DockPanel Details {get;} // This dock panel was created by code and contains
                                  // various elements not predictable at compile time
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Model, the `LogEntry` class, should not reference a UI control. Instead it should contain the data needed by the UI, and the XAML should define a DataTemplate that uses that data. For example,

```
public class LogEntry
{
  public string Type {get;}
  public ObservableCollection<IDetail> Details {get;}
}

<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Details">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Details}" />
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

You mentioned that the DockPanel in the `LogEntry` created items that were not known at runtime. Can you give an example of that? In most cases, you should have some kind of pattern in the data, and you can use `DataTemplates` to define how to draw each Detail piece.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:LoginDetail}}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding CreatedDate}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding UserName}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MachineLoggedIn}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:LogoutDetail}}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding CreatedDate}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding UserName}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LoggedInTime}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

If you REALLY need to store a control in the Model, then you can use a `ContentControl` in your `DataGridTemplateColumn` and set it's `Content` equal to the Details

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Details}" />
```

Comment: I agree with your answer. Binding to a control from the model is a bad practice. Taoist should use `DataTemplates` and `DataTemplateSelector` to decide the correct template in runtime.

Comment: Thanks Rachel, this is exactly what I was looking for
The data in question is XML and can contain a list of text and/or object entries.  Now I can bind that to the content of a panel, I can consider template selectors for the various kinds of object (the project is still at an early stage so maybe later...)

Comment: @Taoist WPF can actually bind to XML the same way it would bind to a class, so perhaps you can use that to your advantage.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I cant give you an exact answer as I dont have VS where I am right now here but a few pointers.

First instead of using your method to add Listview items you want to create an ObservableCollection with your data. Then you can bind the itemssource of your listview to the observableCollection.

Next you can create an itemtemplate for the listview containing the control you want, something quite simple would be like a stack panel with horizontal orientation and two textboxes.

Once you have done that because you have set the itemsource of the listview to the ObservableCollection you can just bind the textbox to the String property within your collection.

Note that ObservableCollection is better to bind to than List as ObservableCollection supports NotifyPropertyChanged().

Comment: Thanks for the reply
I did consider binding the items in the manner you suggested but I perform a little bit of conditional highlighting in the add function (omitted as it's doesn't affect my the problem I'm having)

I've added a little more to the question in the hope of making my problem clearer.

Comment: No problem, If no one has answered this i'll try it out when i get home and see if i can give you an answer. On the point about conditional formatting though you can do that with the binding method I mentioned using styles and triggers.

Answer (score 0):

I have copied your code into a new project and created the same list view here is the code. And this one worked and displayed to data correctly

XAML:

```
 <ListView x:Name="MyList" ItemsSource="{Binding MyListDetails}">
    <ListView.View>
      <GridView>
         <GridViewColumn Header="Type" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Firstname}"/>
         <GridViewColumn Header="Details" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Lastname}"/>
      </GridView>
 </ListView.View>
```

ViewModel:

```
 private List<Contact> _details= new List<Contact>();;
    public List<Contact> MyListDetails
    {
        get
        {
            return _details;
        }
        set
        {
            _details = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("MyListDetails");
        }
    }

 public void AddEntry(LogEntry entry)
 {
   MyListDetails.Add(entry);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response
I also had this working with string properties
Can you now make it work with one of the list item properties set to an Element like in the class at the bottom of my question?
This is the issue I have a problem with